# Getting client side script to run in zombie.js

Tags: zombie.js

I'm using Zombie.js for testing with Cucumber-js, and I can't seem to get my client side scripts to run.

Visiting the page:

```
this.browser.visit("http://localhost/boic",function(e, browser,status,errors){

        console.log('status',status);
        console.log('error',errors);
        console.log('console',browser.text("H1"));
});
```

Returns a status of 200, no errors, and displays the H1 text correctly. However, if I include a script to change the H1 code in the page:

```
<script>
$('H1').html('hello world');
</script>
```

The H1 text remains unchanged, and no global variables are accessible via browser.window...

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you load jQuery in your page before the script is called?

there is also the runScripts browser option but that defaults to true.

But I'm gonna recommend running an external phantom.js process and going through the webdriver interface.  Just because I spent 6 months trying to get zombie to do what I wanted and phantomjs made it all easy.  http://phantomjs.org/release-1.8.html https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda

Answer (score 1):

I agree w/ Jon Biz.  Zombie is difficult to work with.  Many sites that use JS libraries that might contain minor errors cause it to crash (I think node fails) when the zombie browser encounters them - if you have the runScripts option set.  This makes it very hard to use for any application/site that requires external JS - ie most of them.

I also recommend switching to Phantomjs.